# Boolean Modifier Being Ignored

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, 3d-view, boolean-modifier

I've been trying to create a cartoon-like mouth however when I go to render (and even sometimes in the viewport) the boolean modifier that is making the mouth visible is ignored.

This is what I'm hoping for where the model shows an open mouth that is visible:
[image: Two models "stand" next to each other. One has a opening in its front with a visible tongue, the other does not.]

However, if I tell Blender to render the file or interact with the object that's creating the mouth cutout the main model seems to ignore the boolean modifier:
[image: Two models "stand" next to each other. This time neither have an open mouth, however the one that should have a mouth (based on when it worked) has a blue bump sticking out of the mesh.]

Currently the way that I have the model set up is three objects and two armatures. One object and armature belongs to the main body, meanwhile the other armature controls the mouth. There, one object serves as the cut-out mouth and is used within the boolean modifier meanwhile the other object is the mouth interior.
[image: Two models "stand" next to each other. The left model is labeled "Model without mouth" meanwhile the right model has three labels. The main structure of this model is labeled the "Body Object," a wireframe near the upper third of the model is labeled "mouth cutout object," and inside of the wireframe is an object with an orange highlight surrounding it labeled "Mouth Object". At the bottom of the image is the note: Armatures Hidden.]

For the "mouth" objects the modifiers are Mirror > Armature > Subdivision. The "body" object has the same modifiers (Mirror > Armature > Subdivision) with the boolean modifier as the last modifier. The boolean modifier is set difference, "mouth-cutout" object, solver: exact, solve options: self interaction, hole tolerant. Currently it works when I edit the "body" object's modifiers, but as soon as I press render or edit the "mouth-cutout" object the boolean modifier stops working.

I found that regardless of whether or not the viewport is showing the boolean modifier as working, the boolean modifier works when rendering with Eevee rendering engine but *does not* work in Cycles (which is my intendent rendering engine). This seems to imply that the issue I'm running into impacts the Viewport and Cycles, but not Eevee.

If anyone would be able to help me and let me know what's going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: See, if "use modifier during render" is active or not. Its the little camera looking button next to the modifier name in modifier stack

Comment: Hi, try to check if your Subdivision levels on the "Boolean" object and the "Figure" are the same (to see the error), in terms of Viewport and Render. For example if your figure has SubD Viewport on 2, but Render on 3, you will not be able to see the error that happens during render. On the other hand, you can use Boolean with SubD levels of 2,2 on object that has 3,3.

Comment: @JanHrodek currently all of the objects have SubD levels of (2,2). Is that what you were referring to? Would that possibly cause any problems (this said, I also tested out one object having (2,2) and the other (3,3) as well as vis-versa, so I don't think it's the issue in this case, but I'm curious for future reference).